# Remove last character, then concatenate two strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, concatenation

Is below an acceptable way of removing the last char from the first string, then concatenating it with a second string?

```
char *commandLinePath = server_files_directory;
commandLinePath[strlen(commandLinePath)-1] = 0;

char fullPath[strlen(commandLinePath) + strlen(requestPath)];
strcpy(fullPath, commandLinePath);
strcat(fullPath, requestPath);
```

Let's assume server_files_directory is fine (char *) and has been initialized.

What I'm worried about is: if the removing part is correct and if the size of the resulting fullPath is correct, etc.

Comment: It depends on what `server_files_directory` is. For example, modifying string literal is illegal.

Comment: char *server_files_directory;

Comment: Dereferencing uninitialized variable having automatic storage duration or `NULL` is illegal.

Comment: Let's assume server_files_directory is fine and has been initialized.

Comment: What I'm worried about is: if the removing part is correct and if the size of the resulting fullPath is correct, etc.

Comment: Let me also assume that `requestPath` is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not acceptable because there is no space to store terminating null character in `fullPath`.

The declaration should be (add `+1`)

```
char fullPath[strlen(commandLinePath) + strlen(requestPath) + 1];
```

**UPDATE:** alternative way without breaking what is pointed by `server_files_directory`:

```
size_t len1 = strlen(commandLinePath);
size_t len2 = strlen(requestPath);
char fullPath[len1 + len2]; /* no +1 here because one character will be removed */
strcpy(fullPath, commandLinePath);
strcpy(fullPath + len1 - 1, requestPath);
```

Comment: @ajfbiw.s I think you should consider reading a book about `C` and go look for the `pointers` paragraph.

Comment: The example has a flaw. Can you spot it?